# TLV431 based voltage regulator, possibility of exceeding Vka max. at startup

Tags: transient, tl431

I need a small (15mA max.) voltage regulator and considering a TLV431 + emitter follower:[image]

This works fine but the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tlv431) states Vka as 7V absolute max. My input voltage Vi however can be as high as 8.4V (2S lithium ion). During normal operation this isn't a problem because the TLV431 will regulate and keep its cathode at Vo + Vbe, which is well within spec.

I'm wondering about startup tough. Is it possible for Vka to briefly exceed 7V before the TLV431 has a chance to start regulating? Would it be wise to add a 6.2V zener diode in parallel to the TLV431? (During normal operation the zener won't conduct as Vo + Vbe is lower then 6.2V).

Comment: You're using the low voltage version of the TL431. The regular version can go up to 37V for V_KA: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf

Comment: You may consider a cap on Vka for dual purposes.

Comment: @ErikR But the TL431 requires a min. 1mA bias current while the TLV431 only requires 0.1mA. That ends up having a large impact on wasted current.

Comment: Maybe consider the TLVH431: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlvh431a.pdf

Comment: You can place a capacitor across the 431 to provide a kinda soft start as the capacitor voltage (and thus Vka) rises from 0V. Remember that this may affect the stability. Check the datasheet for load capacitance vs stability curves.

Comment: Another 431 variant to consider is the ATL431 - https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/atl431.pdf  The "A" stands for "Advanced" -- https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva685/slva685.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can tolerate using a particular **manufacturer** of TLV431, then use the On Semi or the Diodes Inc versions, which are rated to 16 V. It's the TI version that's limited to 7 V. I haven't checked figures for versions from other manufacturers. There aren't many parts that have significantly different specifications from different manufacturers with the same part number, but this is one of them.

Alternatives are to use the TL431, which can operate at a much higher voltage. The design would need to be adjusted, as it requires a higher adjust pin current, and regulates at about twice the voltage.

A capacitor shunted across the TLV431 will guarrantee that it starts up from zero volts. Be aware that the TLV431 has stringent stability requirements, so read the data sheet and use the right size of capacitor. A small silicon diode from the capacitor to the input would be useful to ensure the capacitor is quickly discharged when the input power disappears.